# Interface & Implementation Woes?

Tags: c++, macros, glfw

Currently, in the game I'm working on, I have a window class:

```
class UserWindow{
    *interface here*
};
```

I have gone to great pains to avoid exposing the implementation details of this window; specifically, the fact that it uses GLFW under the hood. I don't want to expose any of GLFW to the client, in the situation that I end up ultimately removing/replacing it later. All is well and good, until I finally got to handling key input for the window. You see, GLFW uses macros to identify keys, as seen here:

```
auto GLFWKeyPressCallback(GLFWwindow* wind, int key, int, int, int) -> void {
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_???)
        *do stuff*
}
```

As most C++ programmers know, macros are toxic and should be avoided. The problem here is that I provide an UserWindowEventListener interface for the user to connect and receive events from. Question is, how can I expose the indentifiers for these GLFW keys without exposing the entire GLFW API itself? Since GLFW uses the aforementioned (evil) macros to identify these, they would seep out into the global namespace, which ruins the idea of having an "internal" namespace. The only other solution I thought of was having a plain ol' struct that contained static integers for every key, and assigned them in a .cpp file, like so:

.hpp:

```
struct UserWindowKey{
    static const int up, down, left, right... (repeat ad nauseam)   
};
```

.cpp:

```
const int UserWindowKey::up = GLFW_KEY_UP...
```

However, this seems tedious, unmanageable, and generally it feels like bad practice altogether. Any ideas?

**edit**: Some implementation details in psuedocode, to clear up any ambiguities:

UserWindow:

```
//constructor
UserWindow(){
    //key_func just fires the signal that's in the event handler below.
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window_handle, key_func);
}
```

UserWindowEventListener:

```
struct UserWindowEventListener{
    key_signal_type key_signal;
};
```

usage:

```
auto main() -> int {
    UserWindow wind;
    wind.event_listener.key_signal.connect(*MY_FUNC*);
    wind.event_listener.poll();
}
```

Comment: GLFW_KEY_??? seem to be just #defined manifest constants, not macros.

Comment: @bogeyc: sorry, i call anything that uses #define a macro. the issue still stands though.

Comment: To better understand your situation, is the user of your framework providing a callback method that you then pass through to GLFW?  e.g., SetCallback(GLFWKeyPressCallback) or something?

Comment: @MicahCaldwell: I added some details to my post, to clear up any ambiguities. In short, I have a private static member function for each glfw callback, whose sole job is to remove any glfw-specific details from the callback (like the GLFWwindow* argument) and trigger the event signal in the UserWindowEventListener.

Comment: @Shokwav, yes the principle of avoiding #defines stands, but  you're dealing with a third party library here. Since you many want to replace GLFW at some point, maybe an abstract base class hierarchy with GLFW based implementation classes would be one approach, you could implement some other library later.

Comment: @bogeyc: that's basically what I'm doing, but I'm having trouble abstracting away the macros that GLFW uses. I can't expose the macros without exposing the entire GLFW API, since the whole library is in one header.

Comment: In your modifications, when the user calls `wind.event_listener.key_signal.connect`, it takes a function as a parameter.  I am guessing that function is one created by and supplied by the user.  I am also guessing that you want the function to be called when GLFW fires an keypress event?  Also, am I correct to understand that that function (MY_FUNC) signature needs to contain information about which key was pressed so the user can switch on it, but you want them to be able to do so without having to know anything about GLFW?

Comment: @MicahCaldwell That is correct.

Comment: "However, this seems tedious, unmanageable, and generally it feels like bad practice altogether." - best you're gonna get... if it's too tedious, have a sh/perl/ruby/python script generate it using a consistent transformation (e.g. ripping the `GLFW_KEY_` off and converting to lowercase).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create an intermediate method that converts from GLFW keys to your own keys, defined in a way that you are comfortable with and feel is sane.  Personally, I would go with an enumeration like so:

```
enum MyKeys
{
    UP,
    DOWN,
    LEFT,
    RIGHT,
    // the rest
}
```

Then the user would provide you with a callback, and you would provide GLFW with a different callback.  When GLFW calls your callback, you convert the key into your public enumeration and then fire the callback the user supplied.

The pseudocode for your callback might look something like:

```
auto GLFWKeyPressCallback(GLFWwindow* wind, int glfwKey, int a, int b, int c) -> void
{
    auto myKey = ConvertGlfwKeyToMyKey(glfwKey);
    user_callback(myKey, a, b, c);
}
```

user_callback signature would look something like:

```
void user_callback(MyKeys, int, int, int);
```

The ConvertGlfwKeyToMyKey might look something like this:

```
MyKeys ConvertGlfwKeyToMyKey(glfwKey)
{
    switch (glfwKey)
    {
    case GLFW_KEY_UP:
        return MyKeys.UP;
    case GLFW_KEY_DOWN:
        return MyKeys.DOWN;
    // the rest
    }
}
```

The obvious disadvantage of this system is that you have to go through and fill out the Convert function.  The advantage is that you have abstracted away all of the GLFW stuff from the user without having to have any macros or pollute your code with a bunch of structures.

Alternatively, you could choose some other mechanism for mapping GLFW keys to MyKeys.  If the GLFW keys cover all values in a a range, you could order your enumeration in the same order and then just offset and typecast from the GLFW int to your enum.